# Model object load/access relation model in controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Using laravel I have a method that I am posting to in my Controller:

```
public function hired(Quote $quote)
{
    var_dump($quote->project);
    exit;
```

`$quote` is created as a Model object but the above code returns `NULL`

I have the correct relationship setup:

```
public function project()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Project::class);
}
```

I understand that I need to "load" these relationship models onto the object but not sure how??

I thought that when I access `->project` the relationship would be automatically loaded...

Thanks

Comment: How are you calling your `hired(Quote $quote)` method?

Comment: route file: `Route::post('quote/{quote_id}/hired', 'QuoteController@hired')->name('quote.hired');`

Comment: Is your hired method retrieving a legitimate quote? Can you access other properties on the object?

Comment: Yes. I can... $quote->id etc

Comment: Try adding the column name in the `return $this->belongsTo(Project::class, 'project_id');`

Comment: Looks to me like there's no related Project in your database. You're right that it should get automatically loaded. Can you show your schema & the data rows that you expect to be related?

Comment: Scott thanks so much for the help! I was a noob - testing $quote->id actually returned NULL. I had dumped the $quote object and did not notice that it was a empty model object - in turn I found my mistake. Which was not using the correct naming convention in my route {quote_id} needed to match the argument {quote}

Comment: Thanks for helping @mopo922

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you maintain the same naming convention for the variable in your route and method arguments.

Example:

```
Route::post('quote/{quote_id}/hired', 'QuoteController@hired')->name('quote.hired');
```

Should then be in the controller:

```
public function hired(Quote $quote_id) {
```

Thanks to @scottevans93 for leading me to my mistake.